# Which is better for mobile analytic Localytics or GoogleAnalytics?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, analytics

I wanna use  mobile analytics inside my iPhone app, i have read about both they are similar to each other but some persons say that Localytics is better and others say the GoogleAnalytics is better, advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently  using Localytics inside my app , it is good analytics but it has disadvantage compared to google analytics which is you can track limited events per user and if you tried to register more than that number they will remove all your events attributes, so that i will remove my localytis account and start using google analytics because it does not use such limiting , because of the importance of the events and there attributes i will leave localytics and go google analytics , All other analytics  things the same

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between Localytics and Google Analytics is that Localytics is designed for apps, not websites. Localytics collects a richer data set by default and allows you to create any number of events with any number of attributes (GA limits you to just one). SDKs are available for all leading platforms, are very lightweight and provided in source code.

Localytics has both free and paid versions. The free version, called Community, does have some limits on event occurrences, collecting personal data and data cardinality, but very few customers hit those limits. And unlike Google, Localytics doesn't sample your app usage. Additionally, Localytics Enterprise customers have access to session-level data for integration with other systems.

Much more info is available on our website, including technical docs (http://localytics.com/docs). If you don't find what you need there or you have more questions, please ping me and I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone reading this as of 2015 - Google Analytics allows up to 50 custom dimensions with your events and each event contains three hierarchical fields by default, plus a value field. Google analytics doesn't "Sample App Usage", unless you hit extraordinarily high limits, but does have reporting limits, beyond which the reports will be based on a sample of the data collected. With Google Analytics Premium you can get the unsampled data also. GA also supports tracking users between a website and native apps using a unique member token.